# Python - Data Splitting and Extraction

Tags: python, regex, unicode, split

I am using the Twitch API and i am having issues in understanding how to extract data from it.

I call the API and this is the sort of response i get:

`"name":"user1", "game":"game1","name":"user2", "game":"game2"`

I know i will need to use some `.split()`'s but i cannot work out how as each time i try i get a blank output.

The data i need is the `user1`, `game1`, `user2`, `game2`

This data is repeated several times and i cannot find out how to extract this data from the mass of other data given.

Any links or advice will be grateful, i cannot find any reference to large data extraction like this

**EDIT**

After being advised it was json data i edited the code to parse it appropriately. But i keep getting the error: `AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'get'`

Here is the code:

```
import urllib2
import json

url = "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/'Mychannel'/follows/"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    req = urllib2.Request(url)
    opener = urllib2.build_opener()
    f = opener.open(req)
    json = json.load (f)

    for item in json:
        print item.get('name')
```

Any suggestions to why this error is occurring?

Comment: The JSON you've posted is valid, but because all keys in a hash must be unique, your dict is only going to have 2 keys in it: `user2` and `game2`. Furthermore, when I make a similar twitch api call, I get a very different-looking response. What exactly are you doing to get that data?

Comment: @whereswalden The example API call I cut down, so you would be correct in saying that your response might look very different. Last time i posted here i included a lot of detail, and got told not to so i cut it down. Also, i took out my channel name in the api and replaced it with the `'mychannel' so if you are using that you will get a different response.

Comment: I tried it against some other channel. The problem remains that the JSON you've posted has conflicting keys. Did you instead mean to post something like `[{"name": "user1", "game": "game1"}, {"name": "user2", "game": "game2"}]`?

Comment: @whereswalden Yes, i did. My bad. I didnt think about showing that there would end up with more than one key overall, as it gets multiple of the `names` and `games`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The response is json data; use the `json` module to parse it.

Comment: Thanks very much! But i keep getting this strange error `AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'get'` If you see the original question, i have edited it to see the code i am using to parse it

Comment: Since the json you're trying to load is a string, you need to use `json.loads`, not `json.load`

Answer (score 0):

assuming you are receiving a string back, such that:

```
>>> a = '"name":"user1", "game":"game1","name":"user2", "game":"game2"'
>>> a
'"name":"user1", "game":"game1","name":"user2", "game":"game2"'
```

You can get your first split by doing a split by the ","

```
>>> mlist = a.split(",")
>>> mlist
['"name":"user1"', ' "game":"game1"', '"name":"user2"', ' "game":"game2"']
```

Now you can access the data of each element by looping:

```
>>> for e in mlist:
    print("Data:", e.split(":")[1])

('Data:', '"user1"')
('Data:', '"game1"')
('Data:', '"user2"')
('Data:', '"game2"')
```